# awk comparison on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, awk, comparison

I'm trying to write a script that check the disk usage of remote clients. There is a filter in script for meaningful output:

```
...

ssh server "sudo df -Ph 2>/dev/null \
| tail -n +2 \
| grep -v tmpfs \
| grep G| sed s/%//g \
| sed s/G//g \
| awk '{ if($5 < 20) print $0;}'" #to get only disks that the usage is under %20

...
```

This commandline runs successfully on CentOS/RHEL machines but there is an error about awk command in Ubuntu, like below:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { if( < 20) print bash;}
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
```

How can I make comparison in awk in Ubuntu? Operators like "-gt, -ge..." doesn't work also.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison is fine, the problem is that you're missing the variable to compare against. Because your entire SSH command line is inside double quotes, the `$5` is eaten by your local shell before it even gets to 'ssh' – you must type it as `\$5` to avoid that. Same goes for the `$0` later (notice how the error message says "print bash;" in its place).

Comment: It is not about passing value. It works on CentOS machines like this from and also when I logged in to Ubuntu and run like this form, the error is the same. So the problem is about something else. But you deserved a vote because this is the general resolution about these issues.

Comment: @Gefolge I replicated the problem `ssh`-ing from Debian to Ubuntu and the other way around. Then I did what the answer says and the command did its job.